# Speed up python w/ sqlalchemy function

Tags: python, performance, sqlalchemy

I have a function that populates a database table using python and sqlalchemy. The function is running fairly slowly right now, taking around 17 minutes. I think the main problem is I am looping through two large sets of data to build the new table. I have included the record count in the code below.

How can I speed this up? Should I try to convert the nested for loop into one big sqlalchemy query? I profiled this function with pycharm but am not sure I fully understand the results.

```
def populate(self):
    """Core function to populate positions."""

    # get raw annotations with tag Org
    # returns 11,659 records
    organizations = model.session.query(model.Annotation) \
        .filter(model.Annotation.tag == 'Org')\
        .filter(model.Annotation.organization_id.isnot(None)).all()

    # get raw annotations with tags Support or Oppose
    # returns 2,947 records
    annotations = model.session.query(model.Annotation) \
        .filter((model.Annotation.tag == 'Support') | (model.Annotation.tag == 'Oppose')).all()

    for org in organizations:
        for anno in annotations:

            # Org overlaps with Support or Oppose tag
            # start and end columns are integers
            if org.start >= anno.start and org.end <= anno.end:
                position = model.Position()
                # set to de-duplicated organization
                position.organization_id = org.organization_id
                position.disposition = anno.tag
                # look up bill_id from document_bill table
                document = model.session.query(model.document_bill)\
                    .filter_by(document_id=anno.document_id).first()
                position.bill_id = document.bill_id
                position.document_id = anno.document_id
                model.session.add(position)
                logging.info('org: {}, disposition: {}, bill: {}'.format(
                    position.organization_id, position.disposition, position.bill_id)
                )
                continue
        logging.info('committing to database')
        model.session.commit()
```

Comment: Questions about improving code that already works are better suited to [codereview.se] than Stack Overflow.

Comment: You're running at least 11,659 * 2947 = 34,359,073 queries just to get `bill_id`; how can that *not* be slow? `model.session.commit()` also expires all `organizations` and `annotations`, meaning in your inner loop `anno` is refreshed every single time after the first iteration of `org`, adding another 11,658 * 2947 = 34,356,126 queries, for a total of 68,715,199 queries, most of which is wasted work. You can start by querying for `document_bill` in a single query outside of the loop, then ensuring you don't expire `annotations` on commit. Finally, see if you can do inserts in bulk.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try moving model.session.commit() to the outside loop, so it runs one time at the end. I don't understand how I can move the document_bill query outside of the loop, because it depends on the current value of anno.document_id which is provided in the loop.

Comment: It depends on the value of `anno.document_id`, but that value does not change between iterations of the loop. A simple query you can do is `SELECT annotations.id, MAX(document_bill.bill_id) FROM annotations JOIN document_bill ON document_bill.document_id = annotations.document_id GROUP BY annotations.id;`.

Comment: @univerio Thank you for the tips. I moved the commit() so it runs as a final action. I also changed the document_bill query so it looks up the bill_id based on a relationship rather than a search. With those changes it runs in less than 7 minutes, which is honestly fine for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

My bets, in order of descending probability:

- Autocommit is ON, so you're waiting for disk.
- The query inside the loop "document = model.session.query(model.document_bill)...." is slow (use EXPLAIN ANALYZE).
- most of the time is actually spent printing logs to the terminal in the inner loop (you should profile)
- model.session.add(position) is slow (no idea what that does)
- (and this one should really be first) Could a SQL query like INSERT INTO SELECT do this in a couple tens of milliseconds? If so, why make a loop in the application?...